# Why does overflow:hidden on an inline-block <span/> make the following text a little bit lower?

Tags: css

If I set `display: inline-block` on a `<span/>`, there is no visible difference, which is good. But when I further set `overflow: hidden`, the following text goes a litter bit lower. Why is that?

I saw no margins/paddings at all.

PS. what I'm trying to accomplish is to make `text-overflow: ellipsis` happen, which requires `max-width`, which in turn requires `inline-block`.

```css
.s1 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden; /* this makes the following text a bit lower, why? */
}
```

```html
<span class='s1'>Hello</span> world (why am I a litter lower than "Hello"?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying `overflow` other than `visible` [creates a new block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), which does not have a baseline anymore, so it can't be aligned with the surrounding baseline.

You can fix up the alignment with `vertical-align: bottom`:

```css
.s1 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<span class='s1'>Hello</span> world (why am I a litter lower than "Hello"?)
```